# <div> for inline images not working

Tags: html, css

I need 9 images to display in a WordPress footer inline horizontally.  I entered the following HTML:

```
<div id="sponsers">
<ul>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/image1.png" width=257 height=67></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/image1.png" width=217 height=29></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/image1.png" width=178 height=49></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/image1.png" width=64 height=68></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/image1.png" width=103 height=162></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/image1.png" width=66 height=56></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/image1.png" width=121 height=85></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/image1.png" width=134 height=36></li>
<li><img src="http://mysite.com/image1.png" width=162 height=61></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.sponsers ul {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; 
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none;
}
.sponsers li {
    isplay: inline;
    padding-right: 0px;
    width: 900px;
    list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none;
}
```

The images are still displaying in a vertical line with three little list dots.  It appears to be ignoring the CSS.  I'm probably missing something obvious, or haven't styled it right.  Any brilliant ideas?

Comment: Are you using `isplay: inline;` in your code or is that just a typo in your code here?

Answer (score 1):

A `.` in CSS is a class, but your `<div>` has an ID, not a class. Switch your CSS to `#sponsers` etc. and it'll work.

(By the way, you dont need to display the `<ul>` inline — just the `<li>`s.)

Comment: Even the `li`s don't need the inline!

Comment: They would need something to display them horizontal. By default the `li` would use `display:list-item` and stack vertically. Floats could be used on the `li`s or the `img` themselves - or `inline-block` could be used, but something will be needed. Personally I would use floats, but then you also have the collapsing parent requiring a clearfix and I didn't want to be rewriting the entire code when his issue was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline from both the `ul` and `li`. Use `float: left` on the `li`. Give overflow hidden to the `sponsers` div. And the biggest mistake is using a `.` for an `id`. Use `#sponsers`.

**Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/rutwick/NG2nF/**

The CSS I used:

```
#sponsers{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sponsers ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#sponsers ul li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

#sponsers ul li img{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to be fixed.
In your CSS, you have `.sponsers` while you are giving `id` in your markup. That's why any of the styles wont take effect.
Second, to make `<li>` inline you have to add `display:inline`, write now there is a typo, YOU ARE MISSING THE `D` in `DISPLAY`!

So the complete code should be

```
.sponsers ul {
margin: 0; padding: 0; 
display: inline;//you can remove this
list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none;
}

.sponsers li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 0px;
width: 900px;
list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none;
}
```

and in the markup

```
<div class="sponsers"> <!--You have ID here-->
```